# How can I get the timestamp in javascript from a string including the timezone db name

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone-offset

I got the following string: `"2022/05/01 03:10:00"` and I need to create a Date object forcing it to use Chile's UTC offset.

The problem is that because of Daylight saving time (DST) the offset changes twice a year.

How can get that Date object, for example, using the "America/Santiago" TZ db name?

Something like:

`new Date("2022/05/01 03:10:00" + getUtcOffset("America/Santiago"))`.

```
function getUtcOffset(tzDbName) {
..
}
```

Returns -3 or -4, depending the time in the year.

**EDIT:**

I ended using a nice trick for determining if DST was on or off.
[reference](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-date-check-if-dst)

```
const dst = hasDST(new Date(strDate));
function hasDST(date = new Date()) {
const january = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1).getTimezoneOffset();
const july = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 6, 1).getTimezoneOffset();

return Math.max(january, july) !== date.getTimezoneOffset();
```

}

Then I could create the date with the correct timezone depending on that variable.

```
if (dst) {
    let d = new Date(strDate + " GMT-0300");
    return d;
} else {
    let d = new Date(strDate + " GMT-0400");
    return d;
}
```

Thanks everyone!

**EDIT2:**
I finally found a very nice library that does exactly what I was looking for:

https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/Time-Zones#date-fns-tz

```
const { zonedTimeToUtc, utcToZonedTime, format } = require('date-fns-tz')
const utcDate = zonedTimeToUtc('2022-05-05 18:05', 'America/Santiago')
```

Comment: Very similar to [*get timezone offset of another timezone in javascript without using Strings*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888335/get-timezone-offset-of-another-timezone-in-javascript-without-using-strings) and [*Calculate Timezone offset only for one particular timezone*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61361914/calculate-timezone-offset-only-for-one-particular-timezone).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @joaku - Regarding your edit, that will assume the DST rules for the *local* time zone, not necessarily `America/Santiago`.  If you are only interested in the local time zone, then you don't need any of this at all, just do `new Date("2022-05-01T03:10:00")`.  And if you *do* need it to be in a specific time zone - not the local zone, the current solutions require a library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) (or others).  Eventually this will be doable without a library using [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70953763/18762628).
Haven't tested it, but it appears that the simplest solution is:

```
// Example for Indian time
let indianTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", 
   {timeZone:'Asia/Kolkata',timestyle:'full',hourCycle:'h24'})
console.log(indianTime)
```

You can check the link for more complex answers and libraries

**Generals notes**
To get the time zone name use:

```
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
```

To get the difference from UTC (in minutes) use:

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(offset);
// if offset equals -60 then the time zone offset is UTC+01
```

Comment: That isn't what the OP Is asking. What they want is to parse a timestamp for a particular location, i.e. it must use the offset for that location for the specified date and time. This answer gets the current IANA representative location from the host system system settings and the current ECMAScript offset in minutes.

Comment: You right, didn't notice that. Answer edited

Comment: That still doesn't work as it parses the string initially in the host timezone, not the desired timezone.